# How to display Users based on their groups and attendance

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm developing an attendance system but i'm stuck.
I have 3 tables: *users*, *attendance_schedules* and *marks*
*users* has: *id*, *first_name*, *group_name*, *status* etc columns.
*attendance_schedules* has: *group_name*, *meeting_date* etc columns. this table stores information about upcoming meetings
*marks* has: *user_id*, *meeting_date*, *status* etc columns. This stores a marked attendance

On the day of a meeting **attendance_schedules.meeting_date**, I want to display all the users that belong to the same group. However, when a user is marked, it should change the button to marked (i am using *marked.status* to check if it is marked)

The challenge is, when a user is marked, it displays the user twice - one for marking and the other is marked. Seems database is returning the same user (marked and unmarked)

```
 SELECT u.first_name, m.meeting_date
FROM users AS u
LEFT JOIN marks AS m
ON u.id = m.user_id
WHERE u.status = 1
AND u.meeting_group = 'servicon'
```

I also tried

```
SELECT u.first_name, m.meeting_date
FROM users AS u
LEFT JOIN marks AS m
ON u.id = m.user_id
WHERE u.status = 1
AND u.meeting_group = 'servicon'
AND m.meeting_date = '2023-02-01'
```

I also tried joining the three tables but it still didnt work

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question) . Basically...provide us with sample table data, and sample expected output, as well as just the business rule. A DbFiddle to play around with would make it 10 times easier for us too. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Select Distinct:

```
 SELECT Distinct u.first_name, m.meeting_date
FROM users AS u
LEFT JOIN marks AS m
ON u.id = m.user_id
WHERE u.status = 1
AND u.meeting_group = 'servicon'
```